# Pasting Excel cell as Image in Jodit WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, wysiwyg, jodit

Is there any `config` in the `Jodit` library to paste the Excel cells as images into the WYSIWYG editor?

Scenario

- Copy Excel cells with `Ctrl + C`
- Paste the copied Excel cells as images into the Jodit editor.

OR

Is there any option to block pasting the Excel cells as a table into the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please review that article in that link and edit your question so that it has enough code and detail for someone to be able to help you.